# Creating intervaled ramp array based on a threshold - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to measure the length of a sub-array fullfilling some condition (like a stop clock), but as soon as the condition is not fulfilled any more, the value should reset to zero. So, the resulting array should tell me, how many values fulfilled some condition (e.g. value > 1):

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0]
```

should result into the followin array:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

One can easily define a function in python, which returns the corresponding numy array:

```
def StopClock(signal, threshold=1):

    clock = []
    current_time = 0
    for item in signal:
        if item > threshold:
            current_time += 1
        else:
            current_time = 0
        clock.append(current_time)
    return np.array(clock)

StopClock([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0])
```

However, I really do not like this for-loop, especially since this counter should run over a longer dataset. I thought of some `np.cumsum` solution in combination with `np.diff`, however I do not get through the reset part. Is someone aware of a more elegant numpy-style solution of above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use `diff-styled differentiation` alongwith `cumsum` to create such intervaled ramps in a vectorized manner and that should be pretty efficient specially with large input arrays. The resetting part is taken care of by assigning appropriate values at the end of each interval, with the idea of cum-summing that resets the numbers at end of each interval.

Here's one implementation to accomplish all that -

```
def intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1):
    mask = a>thresh

    # Get start, stop indices
    mask_ext = np.concatenate(([False], mask, [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask_ext[1:] != mask_ext[:-1])
    s0,s1 = idx[::2], idx[1::2]

    out = mask.astype(int)
    valid_stop = s1[s1<len(a)]
    out[valid_stop] = s0[:len(valid_stop)] - valid_stop
    return out.cumsum()
```

Sample runs -

```
Input (a) : 
[5 3 1 4 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 5 4 3 0 1]
Output (intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1)) : 
[1 2 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 0]

Input (a) : 
[1 1 1 4 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 5 4 3 0 1]
Output (intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1)) : 
[0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 0]

Input (a) : 
[1 1 1 4 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 5 4 3 0 5]
Output (intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1)) : 
[0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 1]

Input (a) : 
[1 1 1 4 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 3 3 0 1 1 2 0 3 5 4 3 0 5]
Output (intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=0)) : 
[1 2 3 4 5 0 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 0 1]
```

**Runtime test**

One way to do a fair benchmarking was to use the posted sample in the question and tiling into a big number of times and using that as the input array. With that setup, here's the timings -

```
In [841]: a = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0])

In [842]: a = np.tile(a,10000)

# @Alexander's soln
In [843]: %timeit pandas_app(a, threshold=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.93 s per loop

# @Psidom 's soln
In [844]: %timeit stop_clock(a, threshold=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [845]: %timeit intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 527 µs per loop
```

Comment: While the solution of Alexander is elegant and the solution of Psidom is the most readable one, this solution is perfect due to speed. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses pandas to perform a `groupby`:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0])
threshold = 0
>>> np.where(
        s > threshold, 
        s
        .to_frame()  # Convert series to dataframe.
        .assign(_dummy_=1)  # Add column of ones.
        .groupby((s.gt(threshold) != s.gt(threshold).shift()).cumsum())['_dummy_']  # shift-cumsum pattern
        .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum()), # Cumsum the ones per group.
        0)  # Fill value with zero where threshold not exceeded.
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0])
​
def stop_clock(signal, threshold=1):
    mask = signal > threshold
    indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(mask)) + 1
    return np.concatenate(list(map(np.cumsum, np.array_split(mask, indices))))
​
stop_clock(a)
# array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```