# Python : Above a certain level in a row

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I'd like to find a function which takes a pandas series as input and outputs the number of times in a row this series is above a certain level.
Example:

input:
`myfunction([6,7,6,4,2,6,9,8,6],level = 5)`

output:
`[1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way -

```
def myfunction(s, level):
    m = s>level
    p = m.ne(m.shift(1)).cumsum()
    return m*(p.groupby(p).cumcount()+1)
```

If you need negative range values for the ones that are below the threshold/level, at the last step instead simply do -

```
(2*m-1)*(p.groupby(p).cumcount()+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [153]: s
Out[153]: 
0    6
1    7
2    6
3    4
4    2
5    6
6    9
7    8
8    6
dtype: int64

In [154]: myfunction(s, level=5)
Out[154]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    4
dtype: int64
```

Fortunately, for performance, we have NumPy -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46183637/ @Divakar
def intervaled_ramp(a, thresh=1):
    mask = a>thresh

    # Get start, stop indices
    mask_ext = np.concatenate(([False], mask, [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask_ext[1:] != mask_ext[:-1])
    s0,s1 = idx[::2], idx[1::2]

    out = mask.astype(int)
    valid_stop = s1[s1<len(a)]
    out[valid_stop] = s0[:len(valid_stop)] - valid_stop
    return out.cumsum()

out = intervaled_ramp(s.values, thresh=level)
```

**Timings**

Posted approaches :

```
# @jezrael's soln
def myfunction_jezrael(s, level):
    a = s > level
    b = a.cumsum()
    return b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

# Solution from earlier
def myfunction_div1(s, level):
    m = s>level
    p = m.ne(m.shift(1)).cumsum()
    return m*(p.groupby(p).cumcount()+1)
```

Using given sample and scaling it up by `10000x` -

```
In [223]: a = [6,7,6,4,2,6,9,8,6]
     ...: a = np.array(a)
     ...: s = pd.Series(a)

In [224]: s = pd.concat([s]*10000)

In [225]: %timeit myfunction_jezrael(s, level=5)
     ...: %timeit myfunction_div1(s, level=5)
     ...: %timeit intervaled_ramp(s.values, thresh=5)
2.98 ms ± 76.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
8.99 ms ± 40 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
586 µs ± 11.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hey! Great, could you do the same but negative when it's under the level?

Comment: myfunction([6,7,6,4,2,6,9,8,6],level = 5) output : [1,2,3,-1,-2,1,2,3,4]

Comment: @DavidSerero Might be a good read - [`Things you can do when someone answers your question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @DavidSerero If your answered has been answered, please accept it by clicking on the empty green check against the answer post. More info - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/278021

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `groupby` is bottleneck here, for improve performance use:

```
def myfunction(s, level):
    a = s > level
    b = a.cumsum()
    return b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

s = pd.Series([6,7,6,4,2,6,9,8,6])
print (myfunction(s, level=5))
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    4
dtype: int32
```